# Function produces the wrong difference

Tags: javascript, date, difference

I need your help,

For some strange reason, the function below is returning a wrong date value difference of -1 when the Date2 is substracted from the present date.

Date format used is: dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt

Example of proper usage:

```
Date2 (15/05/2016 12:00 AM) - Date1 (16/05/2016 12:00 AM) = -1
Date2 (16/05/2016 12:00 AM) - Date1 (16/05/2016 12:00 AM) = 0
Date2 (17/05/2016 12:00 AM) - Date1 (16/05/2016 12:00 AM) = +1


function test() {

    var date1 = new Date()

    var date2 = new Date("16/05/2016 1:37 PM")

    var diff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24)

    diff = Math.round(diff)

    alert(diff)
}
```

Comment: `var date2 = new Date("16/05/2016 1:37 PM")` is an Invalid Date, date2.getTime() is `NaN`

Comment: Your `date2` returns `Invalid date`.

Comment: From [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): "Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."

Comment: do an `alert(date2)` to see what Javascript interprets your date value as.  It's not what you think.

Comment: @IrkenInvader at least on Firefox, that's a perfectly valid date, and it returns a valid time figure.  It's just not what the OP intended it to be.  It comes out as the "month 16, day 5,  year 2016", in other words, the 5th day of the 4th month of the following year.  April 5, 2017.

Comment: @PaulL I see, I was just testing in chrome.  Interesting how Firefox handles that, thanks for the info

Comment: **Do not parse strings with the Date constructor or Date.parse** (they are equivalent), always manually parse strings. A library can help but is usually not necessary.

Comment: @PaulL—please do not encourage parsing of strings with the Date constructor or Date.parse. It is strongly recommended against because it is largely implementation dependent (as the OP has discovered) and unreliable.

Comment: I made no such encouragement.  I pointed out that a commenter's assertion that the value comes out to `NaN` is not necessarily true.  I also told the asker to display the value he got, as it clearly wasn't was he though it was.  No where did I suggest the asker was doing things the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date receives the following arguments:

`Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

So just replace this line:

`var date2 = new Date("16/05/2016 1:37 PM")`

with this line:

`var date2 = new Date(2016, 4, 16, 13, 37);`

You can also give it a string date like you did but then you need to put the year first, then the month, then the day:

`var date2 = new Date("2016/05/16 1:37 PM");`

Comment: Hi Asaf, I have corrected the date format and that seemed to work however the format dd/mm/yyyy h:mm tt comes from a datepicker, is there a way to automatically and programmatically restring the date before starting to calculate the date difference?